# What speed can I expect using Gigabit over UTP cat 5?

Tags: gigabit-ethernet, cat5

Our LAN is based on a Cat 5 cable, while computers are running on a 100mbs NIC.

I was wondering what speed should I expect upgrading NICs and hub/switch to Gigabit.

Eventually should I replace the patch panel and patch cord cables too?

Thank you

Comment: Cable chunks are quite short, between 20/30ft

Comment: See this realted question for some good information: https://superuser.com/questions/549004/what-happens-when-gigabit-switches-are-connected-over-an-old-cat5-cable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need CAT5E to attain gigabit speed.

[CAT5 does not support 1000BASE-T (=gigabit)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable#Category_5_vs._5e).
There are some exceptions - it is then marked on the cable that it supports it, i.e. "verified for gigabit ethernet".

Comment: I see some users have successfully used Gigabit over Cat 5, probably not reaching full Giganit speed. I wonder if attempting this would completely fail (failing negotiation?) or would simply gain lower speeds? That is, reaching 400/500mbs could be worth it...

Comment: could you comment on my comment? Thanks!

Comment: It will not "fail" as such, but I think it will just drop to 100BASE-T.
Worth a try, though :) You'l have to replace your switches first anyway.
If you consider updating your cabling, go for CAT6 or CAT6A, they are often cheaper than CAT5E (probably because of the demand).

Comment: Arhhh... the question is if the NICs configured forcedly to Gigabit will allow network traffic at lower speeds (possibly higher than 100 mbps) or if data transmission will be refused completely....

Comment: If your switch at the other end is set to 100BASE-T it will fail completely. If it is set to autosensing or fixed on 1000BASE-T, I am not sure. Worth a test :)

Here is a nice [paper](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1205868) on the topic, your Physical layer needs to be set up appropriately.

Comment: Oh well, it's just a bunch of dollars for a 5 port switch.... I'll have a go, the community may benefit from this experiment :-) Thanks again

Comment: Purely anecdotal, but I have a 30m run of CAT 5 from my switch to router; perfectly happy running at 1000 BaseTX.

Comment: I could successfully connect multiple computers using the old CAT 5 cables. Effective throughput is limited to 350 Mb/s uplink and 280 Mb/s downlink. Not too bad, and I still have the choice to change cables!