# one lan port connecting to a switch, will the LAN cat type affect the speed?

Tags: networking, lan, switch, wan

I am fairly new to network setup.

My topology is like this.
WAN->Modem->Router->Hub-> 6 Wireless APs->Devices

I have a fibre connection connected to a modem , then a modem connected to a router and then 6 more wireless access points are connect from the router via LAN (i have a small hub in between router since my router only comes with 4 ports). I am currently using this configuration for my office but since we added on 30 more computers, the network came to a slow halt. 
**Note: i am using cat 5 LAN cable.**

I am thinking of using a switch between the router and wireless aps.
So I just connect a normal LAN cable from router to switch? Will both lan cable and router withstand the load from the switch?

or am I getting it all wrong here, the router just forwards the data to WAN, switch handles the load.

Comment: Is it a hub or a switch? The difference is crucial here as this may be the root cause of your slow network...

Comment: for now im using a hub for connecting router to APs. Im thinking changing it to a switch.

Comment: i'm a bit confuse at who does the heavy lifting, the router or the switch? Im looking at managed switches. like linksys se4008

Comment: Yes, do, as this is crippling your network. A hub has no ability to identify where addresses (MAC) are on the network so when a device communicates with it it simply broadcasts the packets to all the ports on its board. A switch has some intelligence and it learns where MAC addresses are on its ports so it directs packets to the right port. A managed switch allows you to control how the switch behaves with such things as VLANS, VLAN tagging, port trunking etc. This is for the more complex network but you should consider VLANs to separate your network logically.

Comment: A router routes data between networks. Your modem (to the Internet) is the ability for your router to "route" requests from your LAN to computers not in your LAN (web servers, email servers etc. - "the Internet"). SoHo (Small Office/Home Office) modem/routers often have switches built-in so you can at least plug in some ethernet devices. They often have wireless built-in, too. They also provide services like DHCP so your devices can get IP addresses. This is for convenience in building small networks. A switch (in its simplest form) simply takes packets from one port and passes them to another

Comment: The switch does most of the heavy work as all your LAN devices communicate through this when talking to other computers in your office (that includes printers, NASes etc.). The router works by saying "you've asked for this resource but it isn't an address on the local network so I must send it out to the internet (in a nutshell) and I'll get back to you in a moment with what you've asked for"

Comment: I see @BigChris thanks for explaining, its much more clearer now. How about cabling? LAN cable i asked above, should i take into consideration when connecting router to a switch?

Comment: You mention you have Cat5 - is it Cat5e? Ideally the cabling should be a minimum of Cat5e to offer gigabit speed/future proof your network. Because you have a number of wireless APs then your network will be limited to the maximum these offer - but also if your Internet speed is slower then you will be further limited by your Internet requests.

Comment: yes CAT5e. just checked. I'm on a 10Mbps Fibre Optic connection for now. Thanks for clearing it up for me. You can add this as an answer.

Comment: Gigabit is specifically designed to run on **Cat 5** cable, you do not *need* 5e, and certainly do not need Cat 6. There's no harm in going 5e, but a quality cat 5 cable does not need replacing. Needing cat 5e for gigabit is just myth.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to note is that your bandwidth may be potentially limited with switches.
For example, if you have Cat 5 cable going into your switch and coming out, although the outputs are 100Mb/s Cat 5 cable, you will be limited as there is only 100Mb/s coming in. So if you've got two clients at full throttle they will usually balance out at 50Mb/s each see-sawing.
They can however, if noone else is using the connection, use the full 100Mb/s Cat 5.

Shouldn't cause you much trouble however you should keep it in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Let's check the different blocks of your network:

- *Modem-> Router*: Use CAT 6 cable and check if the ports on the modem and on the router can be configured as gigabit /full duplex.
- *Router->Hub*: Replace the hub with a switch and use CAT 6 cable.  Check if the ports on the router and on the switch can be configured as gigabit /full duplex. The explanation to ditch the hub and put a switch is this:

On Ethernet each device tries to send data when it detects the network is free, if two or more devices try to send data at the same time you have a collision. A collsion means that the data being sent is destroyed and all the devices have to try again after a period of time.

A **hub** creates a *single collsion domain*, it means that each collision is "heard" by every device on the network, so when a collsion happens all the devices have to wait a period of time to find the channel free to send data.

A **switch** creates a *collsion domain on each port*. If a collision happens is only "heard" on the devices connected on that port. The remaining ports are free to send or receive data.

- *Hub-> 6 Wireless AP*s: It depends mainly of the bandwith use. The Cat 5 cables shoud work if the max bandwith is below 70 Mbps. Try to not overload the APs with a lot of devices. Keep in mind that if you AP gives for example 100 Mbps, all the devices share the 100 Mbps, and a group of devices downloading data continuosly can easily overload the AP.

P.S. Cat 5 cables support gigabit ethernet whenever you respect the distances  and all your cabling infrastructure is certified, however I recommend CAT 6.

Comment: Cat 5 works fine for any bandwidth up to 1000Mbps.

Comment: @ qasdfdsaq better safe than sorry http://superuser.com/questions/549004/what-happens-when-gigabit-switches-are-connected-over-an-old-cat5-cable

Comment: That's just advocating to allow crappy manufacturers to continue getting away with falsely marked cabling. "Buy Cat 6" is not the solution to cheap manufacturers selling Cat 4 cable as Cat 5.